# Run batch file with my own command in cmd?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way that I can use my own custom command in command prompt with/without parameters so that it will call a batch file and run it? I know something just like 'call someFile.bat' will work, but if my batch file is to find a special file, could I find a way to use 'find blah.txt' and it will run that batch file with 'blah.txt' as a variable? I'm pretty sure not without some 3rd party tool, but anyone know of a way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know, where "blah.txt" should be, you can use:

```
if exist "C:\path to file\blah.txt" echo Here it is!
```

If you don't know the path, it's a bit more complicated. This will search the file in all subdirs of "c:\startdir". Note, that this can take a while, if it has a lot of subdirectories to search for:

```
echo found "blah.txt" at the following locations:
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b "C:\startdir\bla.txt"') do echo %%i
```

to use a batchfile with parameters:

replace `echo %%i` with `call mybatchfile "%%i"`. Note: if it finds hundreds of "blah.txt", it will call mybachtfile.bat hundreds of times.

to use the parameter in "mybatchfile.bat":

```
echo The parameter is: %1
```

Comment: I'm ok with that (I can use something like For /R "C:\" %%A in (mybatchfile.bat) do start %%~fxA) my question is more if you can use a command in command prompt that will recognize it and start a batch file I made with that command.

Comment: Ah - that's a very different question. Yes, it is possible, I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 1):

according to some comments, the "real" question is:

How can I add a custom command to CMD?

Answer: put your batchfile somewhere in your path (or expand your path with a custom folder) , then you can use it from anywhere like any other command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how to create a command (or a `.bat` file) which takes arguments (like a function).

Well if that's what you want, it's actually very easy:

#### Name.bat

```
:: This batch file will greet whoever's name you give as a parameter

:: Check for lack of parameters ->
if "%*"==""(
Echo Usage     %~n0.bat Name1  Name2  Name3
Echo E.g.      %~n0.bat John   Bill   "Harry Turner"
goto :eof
)

:: Main code
Echo Hi %1!
Echo Hello %2?
Echo Herro %3...

goto :eof
```

#### CMD Prompt

```
C:\> Name.bat Monacraft Daniel Hacker09 Qwertypad

Hi Monacraft!
Hello Daniel?
Herro Hacker09...

C:\> Name.bat Monacraft Troll

Hi Monacraft!
Hello Troll?
Herro ...
```

And that's the basics of parameters/arguments for you. To refer to ALL parameters simply use `%*` and to access individual parameters utilize the `shift` command (As you can see this would be useful for `Name.bat`). Below is a code that does this:

#### NameShifter.bat

```
:: This batch file will greet whoever's name you give as a parameter

:: Check for lack of parameters ->
if "%*"==""(
Echo Usage     %~n0.bat Name1  Name2  Name3            ...
Echo E.g.      %~n0.bat John   Bill   "Harry Turner"   ...
goto :eof
)

:: Main code
:loop
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
echo Hi %1!
shift /1
goto :loop
goto :eof
```

#### CMD Prompt

```
C:\> NameShifter.bat Monacraft Daniel Hacker09 Qwertypad

Hi Monacraft!
Hi Daniel!
Hi Hacker09!
Hi Qwertypad!

C:\> Name.bat Monacraft Troll

Hi Monacraft!
Hi Troll!
```

Mona

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to use this bat:
like perhaps:

C:>mybatfile.bat 123456789KEY

```
set KEY="%*"
echo %KEY%
```

Will show:
123456789KEY